# Perform Hardcoded search in Google Maps on Android App

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making my first android app to track and manage medications.

One of the features I want to include is adding a page that says '"Find Local Pharmacies'.

What I want is very simple - when the user opens this page I want a map to appear with pins on all the places that matched the term 'pharmacy' (within say a 5km radius).

I have never used Google Maps API before so I don't know if this sort of thing is even possible - online searches suggest Google doesn't have a 'search' API, but is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/).  I see they've got a [place type](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/supported_types) of "pharmacy".